# does the iPhone support 24-bit PNG with alphatransparency?

Tags: iphone, png

I do know the iPhone prefers PNG. But also PNG-24 with alphatransparency? I hope it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think even if it does the png would probably be optimized down to eight bits by pngcrush on deployment... why do you need such a high level of color accuracy?

I forgot to mention that transparency is supported.  And come to think of it, 24 bit png is just eight bits per channel (I was thinking 16) so.. yes!

Answer (score 2):

Some info from the [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) documentation:

> For all images and icons, the PNG format is recommended (**avoid using interlaced PNGs**).
>
> The **standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits** (8 bits each for red, green, and blue), plus an 8-bit alpha channel.
>
> You do not need to constrain your palette to web-safe colors. Although you can use alpha transparency in the icons you create for navigation bars, toolbars, and tab bars, do not use it in application icons.